# Docker-compose filebeat container is not able to push docker container logs to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am running ELK and filebeat inside two different host separate docker-compose.yml. But filebeat cannot connect to logstash. I can properly telnet into logstash `telnet a.b.c.d 5044` after I wait for the logstash pipelines to start.

Server Side (a.b.c.d)

This is my ELK stack file.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  Elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      discovery.type: single-node
      xpack.security.enabled: false
    ports:
    - '9200:9200'
    - '9300:9300'

  Logstash:
    image: logstash:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./logstash/:/logstash_dir
    command: logstash -f /logstash_dir/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
      - Elasticsearch
    ports:
    - '9600:9600'
    - '5044:5044'
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"

  Kibana:
    image: kibana:7.16.2
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    ports:
    - '5601:5601'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - Elasticsearch
volumes:
  elastic_data: {}
```

This is my logstash.conf

```
input{
  beats{
    port => "5044"
      }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "logstash-2023.07.25-000001"
    }
}
```

Client Side (e.f.g.h)

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.0.1
    build: filebeat
    container_name: filebeat
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
      - type: bind
        source: /var/lib/docker
        target: /var/lib/docker
configs:
  fb_config:
    file: /mnt1/filebeat/config/filebeat.yml
```

This is my filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'


output.logstash:
  hosts: ["a.b.c.d:5044"]
```

Do anyone can help here, how can I push my logs to logstash through filebeat?

Answer (score 0):

resolved this issue by updating the mounting of filebeat configurations

Updated filebeat docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.0.1
    build: filebeat
    container_name: filebeat
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
    configs:
      - source: fb_config
        target: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    volumes:
      - filebeat:/usr/share/filebeat/data
      - /var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  filebeat:

configs:
  fb_config:
    file: /mnt1/filebeat/config/filebeat.yml
```